# Typescript append object to existing object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

I'm stuck at one point. I have an `consolidatedObj` object

```
const consolidatedObj = {
    "flag": "Data Concept",
    "UpdateDC": {
        "id": 732,
        "oId": 695112,
        "cType": "DCON",
        "clientId": 1,
        "aId": 236,
        "fType": "DAT_OWN",
        "details_1": {},
        "details_2": {}
    }
}
```

and I've `anotherPayload`  object which I need to append it to consolidated object

```
const anotherPayload = {
        flag: 'LOB',
        UpdateLOB: {
          assessmentId: +this.assessmentId,
          lobId: +this.lob['id'],
        }
      };
```

Below O/P

```
const consolidatedObj = {
    "flag": "Data Concept | LOB",
    "UpdateDC": {
        "id": 732,
        "oId": 695112,
        "cType": "DCON",
        "clientId": 1,
        "aId": 236,
        "fType": "DAT_OWN",
        "details_1": {},
        "details_2": {}
    },
    "UpdateLOB": {
          "assessmentId": +this.assessmentId,
          "lobId": +this.lob['id'],
    }
}
```

How can I add the below object to the existing consolidate object and append the flag value seperated by `pipe(|)` symbol

Comment: What have you tried? What part don't you know how to do? Is there some issue with just doing `consolidatedObj.UpdateLob = anotherPayload.UpdateLob`?

Comment: @GuyIncognito How would you append the flag separated by pipe symbol? I don't want to hardcode it

Comment: Questions on how to add a property to an object, how to modify the property of an object, how to concatenate two strings, etc. have been answered ad nauseam, on this site and others. Any entry-level JavaScript tutorial should cover this.

Comment: `consolidatedObj.flag += " | " + anotherPayload.flag`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I'm closing this question since its answered many time, anyways thanks for the guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const consolidatedObj = {
  "flag": "Data Concept",
  "UpdateDC": {
    "id": 732,
    "oId": 695112,
    "cType": "DCON",
    "clientId": 1,
    "aId": 236,
    "fType": "DAT_OWN",
    "details_1": {},
    "details_2": {}
  }
}

const anotherPayload = {
  flag: 'LOB',
  UpdateLOB: {
    assessmentId: 123,
    lobId: 321,
  }
};

function mergeObjects() {
  let responseObj = {};
  for (let arg = 0; arg < arguments.length; arg++) {
    for (let prop in arguments[arg]) {
      // if property is str and already exist in responseObj = concat with existing
      if (responseObj[prop] && typeof responseObj[prop] === 'string') {
        responseObj[prop] += ' | ' + arguments[arg][prop];
      } else {
        // else just add obj prop to response
        responseObj[prop] = arguments[arg][prop];
      }
    }
  }
  return responseObj;
}

console.log(
  mergeObjects(consolidatedObj, anotherPayload)
);
```